# strtotime devuelve 1969-12-31

Tags: php

Cuando el campo `Fecha` está vacío la variable `$Fecha2` devuelve *1969-12-31*. Cuando está completo funciona perfecto.

Dejo esta porción de código:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Fecha']))
{
$Fecha1=$_POST['Fecha'];
$Fecha2= date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', 
$Fecha1))); 
}else{
$Fecha2="";
}
```

Comment: En que formato está `$_POST['fecha']` ?

Comment: Básicamente `strtotime()` te está devolviendo `false` porque la fecha no es correcta. Las marcas de tiempo de unix son el número de segundos desde el 1 de Enero del 1970 00:00:00 UTC, por lo que 1969-12-31 marca el día antes por temas de tu franja horaria (tiene pinta de que tu franja horaria es americana).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que la función [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) te está devolviendo `false` cuando la conversión a fecha de la cadena de texto falla.

Al ser pasado ese `false` como segundo parámetro de [`date()`](http://php.net/date) está devolviendo la fecha 1 de Enero del 1970 00:00:00 UTC en tu franja horaria porque `false` se evalúa como la marca de tiempo UNIX `0` (cero).

Si estás en el continente americano (tienes una franja horaria negativa) entonces te dará como resultado el día anterior, el 31 de diciembre de 1969.

Ejemplos:

```
<?php
$timezones = [
  'Europe/Madrid',
  'America/Montevideo',
];
foreach($timezones as $timezone) {
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  echo $timezone, ': ', date('Y-m-d', false), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Resultado:

```
$ php pruebas.php
Europe/Madrid: 1970-01-01
America/Montevideo: 1969-12-31
```

Si quieres detectar que la conversión fue errónea entonces debes comprobar la salida de `strtotime()`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Fecha'])) {
  $Fecha1 = $_POST['Fecha'];
  /* Almacenamos la marca de tiempo (timestamp) como variable */
  $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $Fecha1));
  /* Comprobamos su contenido para saber si se convirtió la fecha correctamente */
  if ($timestamp !== false) {
    /* En caso positivo generamos la fecha */
    $Fecha2 = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
  } else {
    /* En caso negativo hacemos algo con la cadena o lanzamos un error */
    $Fecha2 = 'ERROR EN FECHA';
  }
} else {
  $Fecha2 = "";
}
```

Comment: Muy didáctica y correcta tu respuesta pero no responde a mi pregunta. 
Porque el problema es que cuando el campo Fecha está en blanco, lo que necesito es que la variable $Fecha sea nula o "".

Comment: Disculpa, me pillaste editando. Además, tu pregunta dice "strtotime devuelve 1969-12-31", por lo que expliqué el motivo por el que lo hace. No veo ninguna otra pregunta. Si tienes alguna duda o tu pregunta es otra dímelo.

Comment: Genial, ya lo pruebo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra haber sido de ayuda :) ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Si te interesa escribir un código controlado propongo lo siguiente:

- Evaluar el POST con un operador ternario
- Construir la fecha usando `DateTime`, estableciendo un control de posibles fechas erróneas

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $fechaPost=( empty($_POST['Fecha']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['Fecha'];
    $mFecha= NULL;
    if ($fechaPost)
    {
        try 
        {
            $mFecha=new DateTime($fechaPost);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    /*Probando el resultado*/
    var_dump($mFecha);
?>
```

El código asigna a la variable final `$mFecha` el valor `NULL` por defecto, y sólo cambiará cuando haya una fecha válida.

#### Algunas pruebas:

```
$_POST=["Fecha"=>""];
```

***Salida:***

```
NULL
```

---

Con una fecha errónea.

```
$_POST=["Fecha"=>"21"];
```

***Salida:***

En este caso captura el error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (21) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
NULL
```

---

Con una fecha correcta:

```
$_POST=["Fecha"=>"21-10-2018"];
```

***Salida:***

Un objeto `DateTime` válido:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-21 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Comment: Como siempre mi +1 a tu aporte. Sólo añadir que `empty($_POST['Fecha'])` ya incluye la comprobación `$_POST['Fecha']==""` (bueno, la contraria).

Comment: Gracias por la indicación, @OscarGarcia, efectivamente el `||` sobra. Es que probé el código sin el `if ($fechaPost)` primero y por eso me pasaba cuando el valor era igual a `""`, ahora simplifico...